# Is there a way to read/write tethering (wifi) on an android phone programmatically?

Tags: android, android-wifi, tethering, hotspot

Is there any way to read/write Pre-defined default configure Mobile hotspot data such as Network name, security, password by programmatically.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Opera max does that.

Comment: @NadeemIqbal, please see the modified question.

Comment: I think it is not possible.

Comment: Do you want to read the already set up hotspot configurations?

Comment: Yes, how can? is it possible?

Comment: are these settings enough for you (BSSID, MAC,  Network ID....) https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html ???

Comment: @NadeemIqbal: Not wifi , Hotspot tethering setting reading / writting???

Comment: @NadeemIqbal, Yes it is possible, i implemented it. i will post the answer soon...

Comment: Good. Post the answer so that others can also use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution for above question,

```
private void HotspotDataWrite() {
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);

        if(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled())
        {
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
        }

        netConfig = new WifiConfiguration();


        netConfig.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);
        netConfig.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
        netConfig.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
        netConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
        netConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
        netConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
        netConfig.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
        netConfig.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
        netConfig.SSID = "EASi";
        netConfig.preSharedKey = "Sharath";


        try{

            Method setWifiApMethod = wifiManager.getClass().getMethod("setWifiApEnabled", WifiConfiguration.class, boolean.class);
            boolean apstatus=(Boolean) setWifiApMethod.invoke(wifiManager, netConfig,true);

            Method isWifiApEnabledmethod = wifiManager.getClass().getMethod("isWifiApEnabled");
            while(!(Boolean)isWifiApEnabledmethod.invoke(wifiManager)){};

            Method getWifiApStateMethod = wifiManager.getClass().getMethod("getWifiApState");
            int apstate=(Integer)getWifiApStateMethod.invoke(wifiManager);

            Method getWifiApConfigurationMethod = wifiManager.getClass().getMethod("getWifiApConfiguration");
            netConfig=(WifiConfiguration)getWifiApConfigurationMethod.invoke(wifiManager);

            Log.i("Writing HotspotData", "\nSSID:"+netConfig.SSID+"\nPassword:"+netConfig.preSharedKey+"\n");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```